# How to get rid of Debug runtime DLLs

Tags: c++, visual-studio, dll

I am using a VS2015 to create DLLs which will be used in a project (which will be run on another PC).

I have build the DLLs in Release version on my PC but when I start the project on another PC, I get following errors:

- VCRUNTIME140D.dll is missing
- MSVCP140D.dll is missing
- MSVCP140D.dll is missing

What steps should I take while creating these DLLs so that these debug runtime DLLs won't be required to the run the project on any PC.

Comment: What do you mean by "start the project on another PC"? Run some program that uses your DLL? Load it into an IDE? Something else?

Comment: I mean that when I try to run the executable of the project on an another PC. The executable need some DLLs (e.g. myDLL_1.dll, myDLL_2.dll) that the created by me. Due to these self created DLLs, I am getting errors as mentioned above when I try to run the .exe on an another PC (becasue VS2015 is not installed and should not be installed on another PC).

Comment: Are you sure it's because of *your* DLLs? Or a *specific* DLL? *All* your DLLs have been built in release mode, with no debugging dependencies? And tghe same for the executable program, it has been built in release mode with no debugging dependencies?

Comment: Its due the DLL only because rest of the project is created in an another tool which is present on another machine too. Moreover, by following the suggestions given in answers below, the errors got changed. Now, instead of missing `VCRUNTIME140D.dll`, I am getting error for missing `VCRUNTIME140.dll`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In spite of it being built in release mode, if you require "...D.dll", then there are debug builds in the mix.

This could be the result of the third party dll you have or there are `DEBUG` or `_DEBUG` defines floating around.

Most likely is that the build (of the dll or the host exe) is explicitly set to use the debug version of the runtime (`/MDd`). [Change this in the project settings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2kzt1wy3.aspx) to not use the debug version of the runtime (`/MD`).

> 1. Open the project's Property Pages dialog box.
> 2. Expand the C/C++ folder.
> 3. Select the Code Generation property page.
> 4. Modify the Runtime Library property.

To assist in the diagnosis of which binary is responsible for the debug dependency, you can use [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com) to track down the offender. It will give you a list (as a tree) of the dependencies of each file.

In general, for missing the C++ runtimes (release version) on a target machine, you should install the C++ redistributable. As of this writing, VS 2015 redistributable is available [here](https://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/download-visual-studio-vs#d-visual-c).

Comment: I have changed the properties to `/MT` and now instead of `VCRUNTIME140D.dll`, I get the error `VCRUNTIME140.dll` is missing.

Comment: @skm. There are still dlls (or the exe) that require the runtime, just this time it is the "release" version of the C++ runtime.

Comment: That said, if the rest of the exe and dlls depend on the runtime, it is best that you do as well. It mitigates a class of problems related to resource management etc.; it probably best to use `/MD`

Comment: @skm. If your are missing the runtime dlls (release versions), install them with the runtime redistributable from MS.

Comment: Thanks, I think that it will work now. But I can be sure only after trying it completely. I will accept the answer then :)

Answer (score 1):

In **C/C++** -> **Code Generation** -> set **Runtime Library** to:

- Multi-threaded Debug (**/MTd**)

And yes, such setting is very much needed if you want to debug a process on a remote machine. So, don't go by others saying, "test with Release build only". Obviously, you'll need Remote Tools installed.

Answer (score 1):

As stated by Niall, you should use [dependency walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) in order to find which part of the project is causing the error, it might not be the dll in issue after all.

My bet is it's just some part of the project you forgot and built in debug mode, which of should never be used for production as debug dlls are not included in C++ redistrib installers.

Comment: Its due the DLL only because rest of the project is created in an another tool which is present on another machine too. Moreover, by following the suggestions given in answers below, the errors got changed. Now, instead of missing `VCRUNTIME140D.dll`, I am getting error for missing `VCRUNTIME140.dll`.

Comment: Are you sure [C++ runtime](https://www.microsoft.com/en-eg/download/details.aspx?id=48145) for VS2015 are installed on the other machine?